# How to parse a PDF in nodejs

Tags: pdf2json

I am trying to parse a pdf and categorize information based on text formatting/decoration. How do you suggest I do that?
For example, I have a pdf in which the structure is repeated:
`S.No. BOLD+UNDERLINED TITLE para`

How do I categorize this data into an array of objects based on text decoration:

```
[ 
  { sno: "", title: "", desc: "" }, 
  ... 
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the documentation for [pdf2json](https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json#page-object-reference) and figured that I might have to use `pdfData.formImage.Pages[pageNumber].Texts[wordNumber].R[0]` object after parsing the pdf to get hold of values I need.

The property `TS` of the above object is an array, the value at `TS[2]` corresponds to whether the text is `bold` (value = 1) or not (value = 0). I could not find any details on data related to `underline` text-decoration.

I also needed to initialize the parser as follows:
`let pdfParser = new PDFParser(null, 1)`.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757670/pdf2json-gives-me-a-blank-output-txt-file) for more details.